# Flutter: How to send packages as a tcp client

Tags: sockets, flutter, dart, tcp

I am trying to connect to the HHC-NET2D relay device.

This device allows connection to a tcp client. I have not found a solution with which I can send parameters to the device. If someone knows the recommended way to establish a connection through tcp client and send parameters it would be helpful.

**Support**

 1. Support TCP Server, TCP client, UDP

 2. Supporting 4 client connections in the TCP server. Assume that the local port is 5000. Port 5000 can 
be connected to the TCP client.

 3. Support TCP MODBUS protocol.

**Control command**
 
 5. Sent "**on1**" to the **HHC-NET2D** will turn on the **First relay**.
 
 6. Sent "**on2**" to the **HHC-NET2D** will turn on the **Second relay**.
 
 7. Sent "**off1**" to the **HHC-NET2D** will turn on the **First relay**.
 
 8. Sent "**off2**" to the **HHC-NET2D** will turn on the **Second relay**.

> Read more here: https://es.aliexpress.com/item/32358735415.html

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomeApp(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeAppState createState() => _HomeAppState();
}

class _HomeAppState extends State<HomeApp> {
  Socket socket;
  String name;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(name == null ? 'NO CONNECTED' : name),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Connect'),
              onPressed: (){
                connect();
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Send Data'),
              onPressed: (){
                sendData();
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // Socket connection
  void connect() {
    Socket.connect("ipHere", portHere).then((Socket sock) {
      socket = sock;
      socket.listen(
          dataHandler,
          onError: errorHandler,
          onDone: doneHandler,
          cancelOnError: false
      );
    });
  }
  void dataHandler(data){
    setState(() {
      name = new String.fromCharCodes(data).trim();
    });
  }
  void errorHandler(error, StackTrace trace){
    print(error);
  }
  void doneHandler(){
    socket.destroy();
  }
  void sendData(){
    //socket.write(...)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a string variable with the message you want to send.

And in your code update this:

```
socket.write(HERE_STRING_MESSAGE);
```