# why noip address not work in IOWebSocketChannel?

Tags: flutter, dart

I change the IP address from this code:

```
final channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
  Uri.parse('wss://echo.websocket.events'),
);
```

source: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/web-sockets

to my address from https://www.noip.com/ and dosent work, i use parse('ws://80.200.14.16'), and dosent work why ?

after searching i find this :
[Flutter: How to send packages as a tcp client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58582428/flutter-how-to-send-packages-as-a-tcp-client)

an other way to maybe work with noip.com but
how i can read(receive) the value

Answer (score 0):

You can read data by the dataHandler from

```
void connect() {
Socket.connect("ipHere", portHere).then((Socket sock) {
  socket = sock;
  socket.listen(
      dataHandler,
      onError: errorHandler,
      onDone: doneHandler,
      cancelOnError: false
  );
});
}
void dataHandler(data){
  print(new String.fromCharCodes(data).trim());  // data from socket.
}
```

Comment: to write i use this foction:
`void write()
{
  Socket.connect("10.0.2.2", 80).then((socket) {
    print('client connected : ${socket.remoteAddress.address}:${socket
        .remotePort}');
    socket.write("hello world");
  });
}
`to read i use this code:
`void read()
{
  ServerSocket.bind("10.0.2.2", 80).then((
      ServerSocket server) {
    socket.listen((data) {

      print(String.fromCharCodes(data).trim());

    }, onDone: () {
      print("server done");
    });
    socket.close();
  });
}
`
i get this problem: Failed to create server socket

Comment: Why are you creating server socket you want to connect socket or you want to create socket ?

Comment: I have provide you an example you can use that for read and write both